# PCI configuration

Tags: embedded, x86, bios, pci

I would need an help to solve a problem. 
I work on a system based on CompactPCI platform. The system is composed by:

- 3U CompactPCI CPU Blades (based on Pentium M processor)
- 3U CompactPCI proprietary board equipped with PLX PCI9050 device.

Recently I have changed CPU board with a board based on Intel Core I7.

The problem is that during the PCI configuration phase i cannot read correctly the Base Address Registers for the proprietary board.

These are the results of the PCI scan:

Old (working) configuration (Pentium M CPU board):

- BAR 0 Mem 128 B. 32 bit. Non-prefetchable.
- BAR 1 I/O 128 B
- BAR 2 Mem 2 MB. 32 bit. Non-prefetchable.
- BAR 3 I/O 64 B

New configuration (Core I7 CPU board):

- BAR 0 Mem 128 B. 32 bit. Non-prefetchable.
- BAR 1 I/O 128 B
- BAR 2 I/O 64 KB
- BAR 3 Mem 256 MB. 32 bit. Non-prefetchable.

The proprietary board configuration isn't changed.

Can you help me to understand why the pci local memory seen by cpu board is different in the two cases?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

the compact PCI backplane is passive: the PCI bus is driven by the CPU board. obviously, your new CPU board does not enumerate the PCI bus in the same order than the old board, thus BAR 2 and BAR 3 are switched... however, i have no idea how to correct this.

Comment: I expect that base addresses are different but I don't understand why the size of I/O space and memory space are changed. These values are configured in the eprom of proprietary board.